# How to draw repeating straight lines with specific radius and angle in matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, plot

Suppose i would like to draw an image like the following:

[image]

Where the pixel values are refined to 0 for black and white for 1.
These line are drawn with specific radius and angles

Now I create a 80 x 160 matrix
texturematrix = zeros(80,160);

then i want to change particular elements to be 1 according to the lines conditions
but how do i make them repeatedly with specific distance apart from each others effectively?
Thanks a lot everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be what you are looking for, but generating such an image could be done by plotting a set of lines, as follows:

```
% grid sizes
m = 6;
n = 5;

% line length and angle
len = 1;
theta = .1*pi;

[a,b] = meshgrid(1:m,1:n);
x = reshape([a(:),a(:)+len*cos(theta),nan(numel(a),1)]',[],1);
y = reshape([b(:),b(:)+len*sin(theta),nan(numel(b),1)]',[],1);

h = figure();
plot(x,y,'k', 'LineWidth', 2);
```

But this has nothing to do with a texture matrix. So, we construct a matrix of desired size:

```
set(gca, 'position',[0 0 1 1], 'units','normalized', 'YTick',[], 'XTick',[]);

frame = frame2im(getframe(h),[0 0 1 1]);
im = imresize(frame,[80 160]);
M = ~(im(2:end,2:end,1)==255);
```

Comment: actually I want to generate a texture matrix different r', d, and theta. lol should i consider the matlab code of co-occurence to generate this?

Comment: @user3154371 - Jan de Gier's code is actually quite elegant and it does produce what you want.  However, if you want to specify the constant `d`, you can determine how many to draw horizontally and vertically (`m` and `n`) by taking your rows (80) and columns (160) and dividing by `d`.

Comment: Sorry, forgot about the `d`. Anyway, raryreng has a good solution for that. Please note that `len` has to be scaled accordingly.

Comment: Really thanks for all of you help! btw what is h from getframe(h)?

Comment: `h` is a figure handle. Forgot to paste the line where it is defined, so I just updated the answer. You could btw also use `gcf` ('get current figure'), similar to the `gca` ('get current axes').